# How do i display object in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to display list of user i have this from controller.

```
@GetMapping("/maintenance-user")
public ModelAndView Index() throws Exception
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("maintenance/user/index");
    model.addObject("model",service.get());

    return model;
}
```

the service.get returns an Iterable object

And this is my view

```
<p th:text="${model.Id}"></p>
```

but it returns Property or field 'Id' cannot be found on object.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `th:each` similar to below to iterate the list

```
<tr th:each="obj : ${model}">
     <td th:text="${obj.Id}">Onions</td>
</tr>
```